# is it possible to get a list of all database servers that are available in the openstack cloud using jclouds?

Tags: java, cloud, openstack, jclouds

i have successfully deployed an openstack cloud. i have installed mongodb server and mysql server in two virtual machines.

how can I get a list of all database servers that are available using jclouds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think you'll need to use a naming convention for your VMs running databases. e.g. db-mysql or db-mongo

Then you can list the servers and iterate over the results to check for VMs that what with the db- prefix.

If you're using the ComputeService, you could use

```
ComputeService.listNodesDetailsMatching(Predicate<ComputeMetadata>)
```

If you're using the ServerApi, you could use

```
ServerApi.list()
```